# How do family members earn points in Qantas Frequent Flyer?

Tags: loyalty-programs, qantas

As far as I understood, the only way to get points from Qantas flights is being a Frequent Flyer member.

If I'm a Qantas Frequent Flyer and my wife is not, and we are going to make a trip together, how can we earn the points for her flight?

Can I add her in my membership?

I can transfer points to family members that are member in program, but she is not and I don't want to make another membership, free or not.

Comment: Do they have to be Qantas points? There are quite a few other frequent traveller programs you can credit a Qantas flight to, some of which support transfers, family accounts etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in [another thread about pooling frequent flyer miles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22043), Qantas does not allow you to accrue to a shared account, but does allow you to transfer miles between family member accounts.

> **[Family Transfers](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/frequent-flyer/use-points/family-transfers.html)**
> Family transfers enable you to transfer a portion of your points to an eligible family member, who is also a Frequent Flyer member, up to four times in any 12 month period

What you would do is have your wife open an account in her own name and assign that number to her ticket. After her travel is completed and the miles credited, she should be able to log in to her account and [initiate a family transfer](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/frequent-flyer/my-account/points-activity/family-transfers.html), or request one with a phone agent (for a fee).

See [Terms and Conditions](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/frequent-flyer/discover-and-join/terms-and-conditions.html#jump10) for restrictions. "Eligible Family Member" is currently [defined as](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/frequent-flyer/discover-and-join/terms-and-conditions.html#jump1)

> Husband/Wife, Parent/Step-parent, Domestic Partner/De Facto, Child, including foster & step-child, Brother/Sister, Half Brother/Sister, Grandparent, Grandchild, Son/Daughter-in-law, Brother/Sister-in-law, Father/Mother-in-law, Uncle/Aunt, Nephew/Niece, First cousin

Comment: +1.  The main catch is that Qantas FF membership costs money ($90 setup & $40/year), so setting up family accounts only makes sense if they're going to fly enough to make it worthwhile.  If you value a FF mile at $0.01, that means accruing at least 13,000 miles, which is a fair bit of flying esp. now that Qantas reduced miles earned for cheap tickets on 1 Apr 2014.

Comment: @jpatokal There's a popular loophole for avoiding the QFF membership fee - join Woolworths Everyday Rewards (also free) and you can join QFF for free. I'd link directly, but there's no direct link, so see the QFF FAQs at https://www.everydayrewards.com.au/myrewards/forms/anon/faq specifically the question "Will I have to pay to join Qantas Frequent Flyer or pay an annual fee?"

Comment: Yes, I know I can transfer points to family members, but I don't want to pay for another membership! Should have mentioned this in the question...

Comment: @Sam that's a good tip but I live in New Zealand.

Comment: @Roberto Presumably if you're flying Qantas from NZ, you're heading to Aus? If so, why not join with the address of where you'll be in Australia when there, then switch the address once it has gone through?

Comment: @Gagravarr no, I'll be going to Brazil.

Comment: @Roberto Hmm, ok, do you have any friends or family in Aus who'd lend you their address for applying?

Comment: @lambshaanxy please never let anyone pay for Qantas - it's free each year, and there are many [example links all over the net for free joining fee as well (example on my site)](https://beatthatflight.com.au/index.php/2020/06/18/free-easy-ways-to-get-qantas-frequent-flyer-points-updated-june-2020/)