# Can I get miles for flights I pay for someone else Alaska Airlines

Tags: loyalty-programs, alaska-airlines

I traveled to Hawaii with my wife but I forgot to include my Alaska Mileage  plan when I reserved the tickets. I submitted my request trough Alaska retro credit website and mine went trough but when I try to enter her information and using my Alaska Mileage plan number but it wont let me.
 Also recently I bought some tickets for my parent and paid with Alaska credit card , can I claim miles for that travel too ?

Comment: Why don't you ask Alaska?

Comment: I don't know of any US frequent flyer program that gives you miles for someone else's flight. Generally, the name on the ticket must match the name on the frequent flyer program account to earn miles for a segment. That said, if you paid with the Alaska credit card and that card gives you a certain number of miles per dollar spent, you'll get the per-dollar miles for the ticket purchase even if you paid for someone else.

Comment: @ZachLipton [American Airlines do - it's call Business Extra](https://www.businessextra.com/). It's aimed at small businesses, to reward the business who booked + paid for the flight, and operates *in addition* to the AA Advantage program. I believe that United Airlines flights can be credited to the [Star Alliance Partner Plus small business loyalty program](https://www.partnerplusbenefit.com/application/) as a second example

Comment: Good point @Gagravarr. A number of airlines have business loyalty programs, but those wouldn't be applicable to someone who wants miles for flights their wife or parents took. Those programs also work very differently from normal frequent flyer programs.

Comment: @ZachLipton They do let you get points from travel you book + pay for that someone else takes, which you can then put towards free flights, so in many ways they're the same!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot. Frequent flyer programs are traditionally designed to reward the traveler, not the purchaser. They were a differentiator at a time when fares and routes were tightly regulated, and the high cost of tickets made non-business travel a rarity; most frequent flyer programs are still aimed at attracting business travelers, who fly more frequently and pay higher fares than typical leisure travelers.

There are programs that allow you to [pool miles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/22048/1480) among family members, but Alaska is not one of them. The name on the ticket and the name on the Mileage Plan account must match exactly, or you will not receive credit.

Alaska does have a program which lets you [transfer miles](https://www.alaskaair.com/mileageplan/ssl/transfermiles/transfermiles.aspx) between accounts, so your wife would accrue miles on her own account, and your mother or father on her or his own account, and you could then transfer them to yours. The rate is quite high, however— $10.00 per 1,000 miles, plus a $25.00 processing fee. To transfer 25,000 miles, the barest minimum for a domestic round trip reward ticket in the U.S. (and quite a rarity these days) would cost you $275, and then you would face the additional fees and taxes on the redemption itself.