# Letting someone else use your frequent flyer mile number?

Tags: loyalty-programs

Let's say it's you and your wife traveling together. You have a frequent flyer mile number and she does not. Can you use your frequent flyer mile number for both tickets or can it only be used for its original owner? Or maybe only once per flight or some such?

In some ways this sounds unethical but in the case of a married couple I think there's some pragmatism to it as well. Let's say 25k will get you a round trip flight to anywhere in the US. You and your wife each have 12.5k so if you want to get a free round trip you'd have to pay to transfer the frequent flier miles to one or the other whereas if only one account got them for both people then you could spend them at no inconvenience to yourself.

Comment: Whether you can do this or not should be covered by the specific airline's Terms & Conditions of Carriage, or whatever separate rules it imposes on the earning and redemption of frequent flier miles.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65735/101

Comment: It depends on the airline carrier. They all have different rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *may* depend on the FF program, but having worked for an airline, no.  The FFnumber isn't assigned for the purchase, it's for when the person associated with the FF number travels.  Names are checked.  If you try and assign it to your wife for usage, it will not be permited.

However, you can (At least with Qantas, for example) both get an account (free).  Then you're free to pool or swap miles/points between each other, for when one needs to use them at a later stage.

Comment: There are [a bunch of airlines with some kind of family program](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/airlines-that-allow-family-pooling/), such as [Emirates My Family](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/emirates-skywards/family-benefits/) or [Lufthansa Mileage Pooling](https://www.miles-and-more.com/de/en/program/at-a-glance/mileage-pooling.html). These allow some enhanced sharing of miles between family members, though you have to check the details for the exact conditions and limitations. The largest US airlines do not and charge fees to transfer miles even among family.

Answer (score 5):

> Most frequent flyer programs only allow you to credit mileage to the account of the person flying. Inputting the same frequent flyer number for two different passengers wouldn’t work, because the name on the account has to match the name on the ticket. Most likely, the miles simply wouldn’t be credited, if the number’s even accepted at all. (I suppose it might work for two people with identical names and birthdates, though.)

https://thepointsguy.com/2016/07/earn-miles-someone-elses-ticket/