# Emirates - Family bonus account with multiple frequent flyers

Tags: air-travel, bookings, loyalty-programs, family, emirates

Me and two other family members all have skywards accounts and are currently all accumulating miles on our own.

Does the family bonus program allow me to earn 20% of their miles on top of them earning their usual sky miles, or does the family program only allow me to earn 20% of the miles they flew and thus give no option of allowing them to accumulate their own miles as they did before?

Comment: Interesting. I can search and find a bunch of FAQs on the Emirates site, but clicking just leads to the general FAQ page. I wonder if they're phasing out or changing the program.

Answer (score 2):

When you sign up for the family program, Emirates assigns a new number to each family member you name.

If your family members want to accrue miles for a flight, they would provide the numbers for their individual accounts. If they want to credit you through the family plan, they  should use the new number associated with the family plan. You don't have to be flying with them, but you only earn 20% of the mileage they would have earned on their own.

If you think about the purpose of loyalty programs, it would make no sense for Emirates to award full mileage to someone *and* another 20% to a family member who is not even flying, but regardless, it's also explicitly stated in the [Skywards Terms and Conditions](https://www.emirates.com/english/skywards/about/skywards-programme-rules.aspx):

> 3. A Family Bonus Member, after his/her Family Bonus programme enrolment, earns 20% of the Skywards Miles a normal (i.e. Blue) Member would earn on Qualifying Flights and these Skywards Miles are added to the Family Head's Account. A Family Bonus Member earns no Skywards Miles or Tier Miles in their own right when travelling on a Family Bonus membership number.
> 4. A Family Bonus Member may also be a Member but cannot earn Miles in each membership capacity for the same Qualifying Flight(s).

Comment: It's common for corporate programs (e.g. DL Skybonus, UA PerksPlus,  BA On Business, plus individually negotiated contracts) to award an additional percentage of miles to a corporation on top of the standard personal earnings, so it's not an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: @user71659 Family Bonus is much more analogous to [Household Accounts](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/executive-club/household-accounts) than On Business, or any other business program. No [family frequent flyer scheme](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22043) allows you to double-dip.